# Android studio - Gradle version is 2.14.1 . Current version is 2.10

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I am not able to build a project in my mac. This was coded by someone else and given to me . I did change my gradle-wrapper.properties as recommended , but still facing the issue

```
Error:(1, 1) A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.
 Failed to apply plugin [id 'com.android.application'] Minimum supported Gradle version is 2.14.1. Current version is 2.10. 
 If using the gradle wrapper, try editing the distributionUrl in /Users/*****/Downloads/android_project/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties to gradle-2.14.1-all.zip.
```

Below is my gradle-wrapper.properties file

```
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.14.0-all.zip
```

Gradle sync output is also showing this error which I am not able to resolve - not sure if it has anything to do with the above

```
Error:(30, 13) Failed to resolve:   
com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.0-alpha4
<a href="install.m2.repo">Install Repository and sync project</a><br><a    
  href="openFile:/Users/*****/Downloads/android_project/app/build.gradle">
Show in File</a><br><a href="open.dependency.in.project.structure">
Show in Project Structure dialog</a>
```

Comment: There is already beta3 version of constraint layout available, bump the "someone else", whether he doesn't want to update (but it may require some fix to code using alpha4, so I wouldn't just blindly change the gradle script). Then make sure you have alpha4 installed (Android studio -> SDK Manager (icon in toolbar) -> middle "SDK Tools" tab -> "support repository" group at bottom, together with "Show Package Details" checkbox you should be able to pick particular alpha4 version of archive.

Answer (score 1):

You are using a local gradle distribution. To change that go to

```
Android Studio -> File -> Settings -> Build, Execution, Deployment -> Gradle -> Use default gradle wrapper
```

And then you will use the gradle-wrapper.properties which actually should point to the latest version.

You can see them [here at gradle distributions](http://services.gradle.org/distributions/)

Answer (score 0):

You `distributionUrl` is wrong. Points to 2.14.0 version. Change it to:

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.14.1-all.zip
```